# Showing that certain ideal is entire ring

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p(x)= x^5+x^3+x$ and $q(x)=x^2+1$ be in $\mathbb{Q}[x]:=R$.

I want to show that the ideal $I:=(p(x), q(x))$ equals $R$.

Now, I think there are a few ways to do this. I could find a unit contained in $I$. I could also show that $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are coprime, since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is a P.I.D. Finally, I could just explicitly show that each contains the other.

Given that a typical element of $I$ is $r_1(x)p(x)+r_2(x)q(x)$ for some $r_1, r_2$, which approach is best for the problem? And how would the proof go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I=(p,q)$.

$p= x^3(x^2+1)+x= x^3q+x$ implies $x \in I$.

$q=x^2+1=x\cdot x+1$ implies $1 \in I$.

Answer (score 3):

With $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ also their gcd is in the ideal $I$. Since this is $1$, we have $1\in I$, and hence $I=R$.

Comment: Ok, how do you show that the gcd is in $I$?

Comment: Because, by the Euclidean algorithm, $gcd(p,q)=rp+sq\in I$, since $I$ is an ideal.

Comment: Do ideals in a Euclidean domain always contain gcd?